# Dynamically Select Number of Filtered Rows In Current Column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way (maybe a VBA) in Excel to select a set number of filtered rows based upon the current column? Current work flows regularly require us to select 25 or 100 filtered rows of the active column at a time.

Most macros I've come across during research appear to

1. Select all data in a table or column
2. Involve a pre-defined column.

I initially thought this would be a strait-forward macro to develop but have had difficulty. The code I found during research moves down a set number of rows but does not appear to factor in filtered rows when counting.

```
Sub MoveOneCellDownAFilteredList()
    ActiveCell.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(2, 0)).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you need to do with them after they're selected? Copy?

Answer (score 1):

The following are just examples (no ready to use copy-paste-solution), but they should give you the right hint to solve your issue:

To select only visible cells of a specific range you can use the [`Range.SpecialCells` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel).

- The following selects only the visible cells out of range "A1:A200"

  ```
  Range("A1:A200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
  ```
- To e.g. select all visible entire rows of the active column you could use something like

  ```
  ActiveCell.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select
  ```
- or to select only rows that are visible and also have a constant value you can combine them like

  ```
  ActiveCell.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select
  ```

Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel) for further options of `SpecialCells`.

---

*Note that I recommend not to use `.Select` at all if you want to do any further actions beside selecting. I recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for a good practice and better, faster more reliable code.*